# Gitlab /dev/tty no such device or address

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent, gitlab

Among the many question already asked none seem to answer my problem.

So i'm trying to setup a ci/cd pipeline with gitlab and i'm stuck in the deploy job with ssh.

So I have a buildserver which there I generated an ssh key pair (rsa).
I added the private value to a custom variable in gitlab.
However i seem to be stuck at /dev/tty no such device or address.

I have checked the permissions on /dev/tty and that seems to be alright.
both gitlab and my buildserver are running ubuntu20.4.4lts and 22.04.1 lts.

```
    deploy: 
  stage: deploy
  environment: production
  image: alpine
  tags:
    - dev

  before_script:
    - apk add openssh-client
    - apk add zip
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - mkdir ExampleProject    
    - cp -R Test /ExampleProject
    - zip -r ExampleProject.zip ExampleProject    

  script: 
    
    - ssh -Tv -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no builduser@192.168.0.95 "cd /home/builduser; unzip ExampleProject.zip"
```

[image: screen]

I also get this, and I have such a feeling it has todo with this.

[image: screen no file or dir]

EDIT:

So for the key I used ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048.

according to this source at gitlab:
[Gitlab ssh keygen](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/)

I added the private key as a variable in my project.
For the key when asked for the passphrase I just tabbed enter twice.

as for the error:

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:06
Using docker image sha256:9c6f0724472873bb50a2ae67a9e7adcb57673a183cea8b06eb778dca859181b5 for alpine with digest alpine@sha256:bc41182d7ef5ffc53a40b044e725193bc10142a1243f395ee852a8d9730fc2ad ...
$ apk add openssh-client
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/6) Installing openssh-keygen (9.0_p1-r2)
(2/6) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.3_p20220521-r0)
(3/6) Installing ncurses-libs (6.3_p20220521-r0)
(4/6) Installing libedit (20210910.3.1-r0)
(5/6) Installing openssh-client-common (9.0_p1-r2)
(6/6) Installing openssh-client-default (9.0_p1-r2)
Executing busybox-1.35.0-r17.trigger
OK: 11 MiB in 20 packages
$ apk add zip
(1/2) Installing unzip (6.0-r9)
(2/2) Installing zip (3.0-r9)
Executing busybox-1.35.0-r17.trigger
OK: 11 MiB in 22 packages
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 16
$ echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
Identity added: (stdin) (builduser@build-server)
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
$ mkdir ExampleProject
$ cp -R Test /ExampleProject
$ zip -r ExampleProject.zip ExampleProject
  adding: ExampleProject/ (stored 0%)
$ ssh -Tv -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no builduser@192.168.0.95 "cd /home/builduser; unzip ExampleProject.zip"
OpenSSH_9.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.95 [192.168.0.95] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.0.95:22 as 'builduser'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:RuQORGBuQwSDQosn3QKNw0tIxSL398OOhPg80CF3VzA
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.0.95' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: check_host_key: hostkey not known or explicitly trusted: disabling UpdateHostkeys
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: builduser@build-server RSA SHA256:caxgh10CwPovoNFrlxrnxkU6GsvfeQND0bOjhft/us0 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
This server is protected.
Ungranted access to this server is forbidden and illigal by law to do so.
Going further you agreed to know the issues and consequences that may cause of your actions punishable by law.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: builduser@build-server RSA SHA256:caxgh10CwPovoNFrlxrnxkU6GsvfeQND0bOjhft/us0 agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
builduser@192.168.0.95: Permission denied (publickey,password).
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 255
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show all of the debug output rather than just part of it. And include the debug output as text (formatted as code the same way you formatted the "deploy" section). Don't post pictures of text if you can avoid it.

Comment: NB the "can't open /dev/tty" messages just mean that ssh can't read a password because it's not being run interactively. You'd expect to get a message like that when running ssh in an automated way. The only issue at that point is that ssh is trying password authentication because it wasn't able to authenticate with a key.

Comment: hmm I created the key pair witouth a passphrase I left it empty according to the gitlab docs, the pub and private key are still located in the /home/builduser/.ssh directory

Answer (score -1):

One possibility is that you have added a key that has a passphrase. That means, your *private* key is encrypted, and to unlock it, you have to type in the passphrase. On your local system you may have told your computer to "remember the passphrase", "store it in a keychain" or some such. But gitlab servers don't have your passphrase.

When gitlab CI/CD servers want your key, they need that passphrase, they try to open a terminal. But they're set up so that there is no local terminal, so you get an error.

The quick solution would be to generate another ssh key, but don't set any passphrases on it.

Edit: updated per comments

There is another possibility: you don't have a private key uploaded so your ću/cd server can't log in with key and is asking for a password.

Comment: This is incorrect. `ssh` is trying to prompt for a password (not a key passphrase) when it prints the /dev/tty errors. ssh uses an internal function which happens to be named "read_passphrase" to read both passphrases and passwords.

Comment: Possible, but how do you know the difference?